# Is it possible to receive sms after closing the app in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am working on a Sms App and I need to upload sms data into list in the app even after the app was closed. How can I do it?

Comment: The BroadCast Reciever will be invoked when the SMS is recieved even if your App is closed. So You can hook onto that. Or you Could access the content provider of the sms and read all the smses but beware it's not part of the API.

Comment: Ok @st0le, when sms is received , broadcast receiver is invoked, and at that time is it possible to store that received message in app or in listview of that app ,without opening that app?

Comment: @Vishnu, So you're saying the List is in the background? The App is "Open" but is in the background? In that case, yes, you simply update the data objects of your activity. (Use a dynamic BroadCast Reciever) and when you activity comes in focus, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` every time to make sure the data is reloaded.